# How to get the index value in a list from substring?

Tags: python, list

I'm reading the contents of a JSON text file and am struggling to get the contents of a specific index in the data.

An example of the data objects I'm reading is below. There are multiple instances in my file, but they all look similar to the following:

```
[{ "value": "hello", "name": "janedoe", "istrue": "yes", "number": 5 }]
```

The console returns nothing every time and I can print `json_list[0]` and it returns the whole value `{'name': 'janedoe', 'number': 5}`.

I would like to use the substring "doe" to search within the list and find a match and then return the index of that match.

I have tried using a function and one liners such as this

```py
res = [i for i in json_list if substring in i] 

    with open ('text.txt', 'r') as output_file:
        json_array = json.load(output_file)
        json_list = []
        json_list = [{'name': item['name'].split('.')[0], 'number': item['number']}
    for item in json_array]

    substring = 'doe'
    def index_containing_substring(json_list, substring):
        for i, s in enumerate(json_list):
            if substring in s:   
                return i
        return -1
```

I would like to return the index value so that I can then call that index and utilize its data.

Comment: Could you please provide a sample of the data in `text.txt`? It's hard to identify what's wrong without seeing what you're starting with.

Comment: added to the post

Comment: `json_list = [{'name': item['name'].split('.')[0], 'number': item['number']}
    for item in json_array]`
Im confused what are you hoping to accomplish with this line. What is this for loop doing inside of the list?

Comment: That loop and line finds the 'name' and 'number' values that I need to be associated with each other. It then puts those values into the json_list variable. I will eventually be comparing a variable to one in the list and see if it matches and if it does I will pull the number value and use that for the next part of my script.

Comment: Please use the generic [python] tag for all python related questions. use a version specific tag at your discretion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just go with a simple loop...

```
def find_doe_in_list_of_dicts(list_of_dicts):
    for item in list_of_dicts:
        if "doe" in item["name"]:
            index_of_item_with_doe = list_of_dicts.index(item)
            break

    return index_of_item_with_joe
```

Or in a really ugly oneliner:

```
 def find_doe_in_list_of_dicts(list_of_dicts):
     return list_of_dicts.index([item for item in list_of_dicts if "name" in item and "doe" in item["name"]][0])
```

Comment: If i wanted to ignore case on the word "doe" how would I go about that? Instead of hard coding "doe" I have assigned it to a variable called sub

Answer (score 2):

Are we agree that you talk about dictionaries inside a list ?
If I understand, you want to have an index to access like this:

```
tab = [{ "value": "hello", "name": "janedoe", "istrue": "yes", "number": 5 }]
% Doesn't work
print(tab[0][0]) // You would like "hello"
```

However, if you know that you just want "value", "name" or whatever, you can access like this:

```
tab = [{ "value": "hello", "name": "janedoe", "istrue": "yes", "number": 5 }]
# Display "hello"
print(tab[0]["value"])
```

You can use a loop like you did and get fields that you want. 
Is it what you want ?

EDIT:

This is the new code for what you want:

```
def index_containing_substring(list_dic, substring):
    for i, s in enumerate(json_list):
        for key in s:
            if substring in s[key]:
                # If you don't want the value remove s[key]
                return i, key, s[key]
        return -1

json_list = [
    { "value": "hello", "name": "janedoe", "istrue": "yes", "number": 5 },
    { "value": "hello", "name": "pop", "istrue": "yes", "number": 5 }
]

substring = 'doe'

# display: (0, 'name', 'janedoe')
print(index_containing_substring(json_list, substring))
```

I've modified a bit, but the function return the index of the table, and which key contains 'doe'. 
Notice in the code, that you just return the first element where you find 'doe' and not all elements.
But it's not difficult to generalize if you want to have all result.

Comment: I don't think so... I would like to search the list with substring='doe' and return the index of the element that it matched.

Comment: Ok, and this substring "doe" can be found only in "value" and "name" ?

Comment: The substring 'doe' will only appear once throughout the entire list and will only appear next to 'name'.

Comment: Thank you for the solution I ended up just using the for loop below!